# Client Cert validation for authentication in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to configure client side cert validation for authentication(MTLS) on AWS ALB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AWS load balancers do not support client cert validation at this time.